# Multicolumn & Multirow leads to an unwanted vertical line

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, multirow

**What I wanted to get:**
[image]

**What I'm getting:**
[image]

**Minimum Working Example:**

```
\begin{longtable}{ | l | p{7cm} | l | p{6.5cm} | } \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Índice}}   & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Artigos} \\ \cline{3-4}
                &   & Total & Referências
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is that happening?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package. This makes merging cells much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two, separate issues with your `longtable` environment:

- double-thickness vertical separator line in row 1
- unwanted vertical separator line in row 2

[image]

To fix the first issue, change `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Artigos}` to `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Artigos}`. To fix the second issue, change the blank first cell in the second row to `\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}`. The effects of the fixes are visible in the lower half of the preceding screenshot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,array}

\begin{document}

% first 'longtable' contains 2 mistakes
\begin{longtable}{ | l | p{7cm} | l | p{6.5cm} | } \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Índice}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Artigos} \\ 
\cline{3-4}
 & & Total & Referências \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}

% second 'longtable' fixes both mistakes
\begin{longtable}{ | l | p{7cm} | l | p{6.5cm} | } \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Índice}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{Artigos} \\ 
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & & Total & Referências \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray`.

You didn't show which document class you're using. Please note that, given its column width, your table goes out of the border, with an ordinary `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={My table}
  ]{
  colspec={lp{7cm}lp{6.5cm}},
  hline{1-3,Z}={}, vlines
  }
  \SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c}{Índice} & & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Artigos} & \\ 
  & & Total & Referências \\  
  A & B & C & D\\
  E & F & G & H\\
  J & K & L & M\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Also with `IEEEtran` your table is too large.